# Does tensorflow.random have functions like get_state() and set_state()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, random-seed

In TensorFlow, we can set seed by

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(1)
```

In my experiments, I wish to save the seed state in order to resume my training in case my execution is killed. I know the default random library in python and numpy.random both have functions to retrieve and set seed's state, such as

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(1)
>>> np.random.rand(1,1)
array([[0.417022]])
>>> state = np.random.get_state()
>>> np.random.rand(1,1)
array([[0.72032449]])
>>> np.random.set_state(state)
>>> np.random.rand(1,1)
array([[0.72032449]])
```

But I don't see similar functions from [its documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random).

How may I save a tensorflow's seed state and reuse it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You cannot extract the current state of the seed.

Long Answer: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335395/6299772).